# помогите разобрать node.js код, в котром я наполняю товарами базу данных?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть такой node.js код из двух файлов с помощью которых я наполняю товарами базу данных.

файл в котором создаю модель:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schema = new Schema({
    imagePath: {type: String, required: true},
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    description: {type: String, required: true},
    price: {type: Number, required: true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', schema);
```

Здесь создали конструктор, но документация говорит что конструктором является любая функция визваная через слово "new".

**Первый вопрос**:
Но в этом коде нет функции, тогда получается что `var schema = new Schema` не является конструктором? или как? или что такое `var schema = new Schema`?

Есть другой файл,который импортирует модель "product" с первого файла, и вот код другого файла:

```
var Product = require('../models/product');

var products = [
    new Product({
        imagePath: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5e/Gothiccover.png',
        title: 'Gothic Video Game',
        description: 'Awesome Game!!!!',
        price: 10
    }),
    new Product({
        imagePath: 'http://eu.blizzard.com/static/_images/games/wow/wallpapers/wall2/wall2-1440x900.jpg',
        title: 'World of Warcraft Video Game',
        description: 'Also awesome? But of course it was better in vanilla ...',
        price: 20
    }),
    new Product({
        imagePath: 'https://support.activision.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00PU000000Rq6tz',
        title: 'Call of Duty Video Game',
        description: 'Meh ... nah, it\'s okay I guess',
        price: 40
    })
```

**И второй вопрос:**
Что такое здесь:

```
var products = [];
```

Я понимаю что это массив, но масив чего? Можно сказать что это массив нескольких new Product, но что такое new Product я не могу обьяснить,могу обьяснить только что оно содержит свойства с значениями.

Comment: У вас базовые вопросы по синтаксису js. Рекомендую почитать основы js, тогда эти вопросы сами пропадут.

Answer (score 0):

Как вам подсказали в комментариях, лучше вникать посредством изучения [JS](https://learn.javascript.ru).

`var schema = new Schema()` - это схема подключения к базе данных, скорей всего к MongoDb посредством мангуста. Про мангуста не особо знаю, т.к. предпочитаю работать через нативный драйвер.

```
var products = [];
```

Это объявление массива, который вы формируете по определенному классу Product(используется конструктор). Вот тут [подробнее](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).